# How to load ActionResult without refreshing layout in MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am working on a website with a form that has a large number of questions to answer, so I decided to group the questions into sections. I want to put the sections in a list-group in /Share/_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href=@Url.Action("Index") class="list-group-item active">Informacion general</a>
            <a href=@Url.Action("Formulario") class="list-group-item">Formulario</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Reingreso/Rehire</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Baja/Termination</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de salario/Salary change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de clasificacion/Classification change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de turno/Shift change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de tipo de contrato/Contract change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de tabla de prestaciones/Benefits change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de niveles/Level change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de tipo de nómina/Payroll type change</a>
            <a href=# class="list-group-item">Cambio de información personal/Personal information change</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each item call or group of questions has its own `ActionResult` and model class, but the problem is when I click on an item that I want to add to the "active" class to be seen in the section or group of questions that is displaying - but when I click refresh everything is erased (including the "active" class).

Comment: Use ajax if you want to stay on the same page, or send a value to the view (e.g. using a `ViewBag` property) indicating which menu needs to `active` class so that you can set it.

Comment: i will try with AJAX first, thanks!

Comment: this doesnt works! the list group appear inside body questions again! :(